# SQL SLOW ODBC CONNECTION

Tags: sql, odbc, jdbc-odbc

I have ODBC connection problem in my pc.
I am using sql 2012 netbeans 7.3 win 7 32bit.
but the same program is running fine on another pc.
I think it's my pc's ODBC problem but I am not getting it..

Comment: This question is impossible to understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution before I was building connection from odbc through SQL SERVER.
but when I tried SQL NATIVE CLIENT its working perfectly.